# Shortest path for positive edge weights, largest path weight known

Tags: shortest-path, directed-graph

Given a directed graph G(V,E) with (positive) weighted edges, is there an algorithm that computes the shortest paths from a single vertex to every other, given the total weight of the largest shortest path to be K, in O(K+V+E) time?